# Could not register service and start it on Centos

Tags: service, centos7, minio

I have installed Minio server on a Centos 7.9 and I am trying to run it as a service.

I used this guide and the minio.service file it provided to install Minio as a service: https://www.centosblog.com/install-configure-minio-object-storage-server-centos-linux/

Now when I try to enable the service I receive the following error. Could someone please kindly help?

```
[root@danesh bin]# systemctl enable minio.service

** (pkttyagent:38702): WARNING **: 22:50:16.320: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject (polkit-error-quark, 0)
```

Starting the service:

```
[root@danesh bin]# systemctl start minio.service

** (pkttyagent:43010): WARNING **: 23:06:46.143: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject (polkit-error-quark, 0)
Job for minio.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status minio.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be because of "Secure processes" in Centos. It supposedly hides all Linux processes not owned by the user.

I had CWP control panel so I went to "Secure processes" section of the panel and temporarily disabled it. After enabling the service you can re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `permissive` mode to `SELINUX`. Open the following file in the command line:

```
sudo vi /etc/selinux/config
```

Then change the following value:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

And finally, reboot the OS:

```
sudo reboot
```

After you enable `minio.service`, don't forget to set `enforcing` to `SELINUX` again.